# Select option does not set the selected value from a response

Tags: node.js, ajax, express

i have 2 select dropdowns which i'm populating with values from a server. i can retrieve the values and populate the options of the select dropdown with no problems, however, when i try to set one of the values of the second select dropdown as the selected value, it does not display.

here's my code:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: "/someUrl",
   data: { nameType: 'Shop', item: itemName},
       success: function (data) 
       {
         $.each(data, function (i, obj) {

           var div_data = "<option>" + obj.Shop + "</option>";
           $(div_data).appendTo('#shop_name');
         });


                $.ajax
                ({
                    url: '/get_shop_item',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: { shop_id: shop_id },
                    success: function (response) 
                    {

                        $('#area_name option').filter(function() {
                            return this.text == response.result[0].area;
                        }).attr('selected', true);

                        $('#shop_name option').filter(function() {
                            return this.text == response.result[0].name;
                        }).attr('selected', true);
                    }
                });
           }
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted only populates one select element `#shop_name`

I would probably set the name property on the options then you don't have to use `filter` and go through all options.

Try this

```
$.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: "/someUrl",
   data: { nameType: 'Shop', item: itemName},
       success: function (data) {
         $.each(data, function (i, obj) {
           var div_data = '<option name="' + obj.Shop + '">' + obj.Shop + '</option>';
           $(div_data).appendTo('#shop_name');

           // append to #area_name as well
         });


         $.ajax({
             url: '/get_shop_item',
             type: 'POST',
             data: { shop_id: shop_id },
             success: function (response) {
                $('#area_name option[name="' + response.result[0].area + '"]').attr('selected', true);

                $('#shop_name option[name="' + response.result[0].name + '"]').attr('selected', true);
             }
         });
      }
  });
```